# Form Submit Not working on IE 10 intermittently with Spring MVC in backend

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

we have developed a application using spring 3.0 and in one jsp we have 2 submit buttons.

```
<form:form name="etsubmitDetails" action="etsubmitdetails.htm" method="post" commandName="etform" cssClass="form-horizontal">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="search" value="search" >
<i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Search</button>`
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="submit1" value="submit1" >         

<i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then we have used annotation for the controller. below is the code.

```
    @Controller
public class ETController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/etsubmitdetails.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST,params="search")
public String search(@ModelAttribute ETFormBean etform, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("etform", etform);
    return "et";}
@RequestMapping(value = "/etsubmitdetails.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST,params="submit1")
    public String submit1(@ModelAttribute ETFormBean etform, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
model.addAttribute("message", "Request successfully submitted.");
    model.addAttribute("etform", etform);
    return "et";
}
```

but the above code is working fine in Mozilla firefox. but in IE its intermittently giving 404 error. Can anyone please help in this issue

Answer (score 1):

Firefox by default put all attribute in the hidden url backgroud. But IE doesn't. So whenever any of the button clicked in the IE no param is generated in the hidden url. So a nullpointerexception is thrown and 404 page is displayed.
So you may do one thing. Instead of using param, create only one method. And in the jsp, create both button with save name but different values. So in the controller method check the button value. And depending on the button value do next step.Your problem will be solved then

Comment: I tried your suggestion. For first 2-3 times its giving correct values for submit request. butIf I leave the screen idle for 20 sec and s=clickon serach then its giving null value for submit.

Comment: Check your server settings.I guess maximum timeout is set at very low. Increase it to 10-15 minutes.

Comment: from application level can we change the timeout. If yes then how to do it.

Comment: Still the problem is not getting solved. Sometimes its returning values, sometimes not.Any other solution